# register_taxonomy for both 'Post' & 'Page'

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pages

I'm using following code to register new taxonomy for WP-Post.

```
function qc22_build_taxonomies(){
        register_taxonomy(__( "fullscreen-tags" ), array(__( "fullscreen" )), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => __( "Fullscreen Tags" ), "singular_label" => __( "Skill Type" ), "rewrite" => array('slug' => 'fullscreen-tags', 'hierarchical' => true))); 
    }
    function qc22_fullscreen_edit_columns($columns){  

            $columns = array(  
                "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",  
                "title" => __( 'fullscreen Item Title' ),
                "type" => __( 'type' )
            );  

            return $columns;  
    }  
    function qc22_fullscreen_custom_columns($column){  
            global $post;  
            switch ($column)  
            {    
                case __( 'type' ):  
                    echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, __( 'fullscreen-tags' ), '', ', ','');  
                    break;
            }  
    }  

    add_action( 'init', 'qc22_build_taxonomies', 0 );
    add_filter("manage_edit-fullscreen_columns", "qc22_fullscreen_edit_columns");  
    add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "qc22_fullscreen_custom_columns");
```

I want to appear this taxonomy on WP-Pages also. I'm new to wordpress. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `register_taxonomy` can accept a string or an array of post types, so simply add the `page` post type to that array, like so:

```
function qc22_build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( "fullscreen-tags", array( "fullscreen", "page" ), array( "hierarchical" => true, "label" => __( "Fullscreen Tags" ), "singular_label" => __( "Skill Type" ), "rewrite" => array('slug' => 'fullscreen-tags', 'hierarchical' => true ) ) ); 
}
```

Comment: No problem, didn't realise i was editting when you were also(edit times are close), sorry about that.